# Background image in div - show completedly in mobile view same as in wide screen

Tags: html, css

Here is my current background in wide screen:

[image]

Here is my same current background in mobile screen:

[image]

My question is, is it possible to view full background like in widescreen in mobile view?

I used css code to background image as below:

```
background-image: url(/assets/img/bg_advantages.jpg);
background-size: cover;
```

Some reference of what I'am doing :

```
.bg-advantages {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
    ), url(/assets/img/bg_advantages.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: by view full background you mean display like desktop?

Comment: Yes...like in desktop

Comment: to my knowledge, the background img changes according to its container. you need to work on the container or post the code of your container alone with its css

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: contain;`

This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size